# How to validate external exposed description field in MVC 4(C#)?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have developed a customer contact form in MVC. Which a description field for 2000 characters. This is completely external facing page. So users can enter any junk data here. I have to send this data in the `XML` format including other fields (like first name, last name ,email adress , etc)  to another system. So `XML` has to accept the text from this form fields.

How can I validate when user enter data, remove un-necessary data from description field.  ?

Comment: Define 'un-necessary data' please.

Comment: What qualifies as unnecessary data? All you have said is 2000 characters. Apart from setting a limit on number of characters you have included little else.

Comment: If you are trying to make the data part of a valid XML document, you will need to escape it and/or put it into a CDATA section: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean

Answer (score 0):

On your property in your model set an attribute on it like so:

```
public class DataModel
  {
    [StringLength(2000, ErrorMessage = "Field cannot exceed 2000 characters")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
  }
```

That way the Users will **remove their own junk** if what they want to put in the field does not fit under 2000 characters.